# jscrollpane colors

Tags: colors, jscrollpane

I'm trying to modify the scrollbar colors for jscrollpane.

This didn't work for me:

```
$('a.athlete_popup_content').click(function(){
    $('#box_on_top').append($content); //.athlete class is within $content
    $('.athlete').jScrollPane({autoReinitialise: true});
    $('.jspVerticalBar').css('width', '10px');
    $('.jspTrack').css('background','lightgrey');
    $('.jspDrag').css('background','black');
    $('.athlete').jScrollPane({autoReinitialise: true});
});
```

i tried placing athlete class both before and after... it doesn't do anything... also, the second time this runs, the scrollbar doesn't appear at all.

any help?

-=update=-
For the issue where it does not appear correctly the second time, I had to destroy the jsp on close and it started working.

```
var element = $('.athlete').jScrollPane(); 
var api = element.data('jsp');
api.destroy();
```

I was unable to get the colors to work.

I am including the .css initially, but want to change the colors on load. I wasn't able to figure out this issue so I just modified the .css

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code es working perfectly, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zE8Zj/19/). If you are calling `jScrollPane()` on a click event then the tags you are trying to reach (`.jspVerticalBar`, `.jspTrack`, `.jspDrag`) are created after `css()` calls, then you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach those calls to the event.

Comment: Thank you Matias, but I wasn't able to get it to work. I've updated the code in my question.

Comment: Can you post your html?? And... styling with css is not an option??

Comment: For the issue where it does not appear correctly the second time, I had to destroy the jsp on close and it started working. 

    var element = $('.athlete').jScrollPane(); 
    var api = element.data('jsp');
    api.destroy();

I was unable to get the colors to work.